# How to populate Kendo UI Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I need to bind data from database to a kendoUI Dropdownlist. I tried the below. But seems not working. Could you please suggest

```html
View: Preview.cshtml
   
@{
        //Layout = null;
    }
    <link href="/Content/MenuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
    h2 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #f90;
    }
        </style>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <h2>Reports</h2>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                 .Name("DeskDropDown")
                              //.Events(e => e.Change("onDeskDropDownChanged"))
                              .OptionLabel("Select Product...")
                                  .DataTextField("ProductName")
                                  .DataValueField("ProductId")
                                  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetProducts", "Home")))
                          
                
     )


Controller Name: Home
public JsonResult GetProducts()
        {
            
           var data = new[] { new { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "abc"` }, new { ProductId = 2, `ProductName = "xyz"` } }; 
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Whenever i run the code, no result is displaying in dropdownlist

Comment: You need to return a collection of anonymous objects containing properties `product_id` and `product_name` (and you cannot serialize you object twice using `SerializeObject()` and then again using `Json()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Could you please share a working code.

Comment: `var data = new[]{ new{ product_id = 1, product_name = "abc" }, new{ product_id = 2, product_name = "xyz" } }; return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. i tried this. but it is not working. Could you please help me. I edited my code please have a look

Comment: What edit are you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write you like this.
This is helpful too: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/remotedatasource

MVC wrapper.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .DropDownList()
    .Name("someName")
    .DataTextField("Foo")
    .DataValueField("Foo")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetBar", "FooController").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
    )
```

FooController

```
public ActionResult GetBar([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<Bar> data = new List<Bar>();
    return Json(data);
}
```